# To determine the interval of unit length which contains the smallest positive root of $x^{3}-5x-1=0$

Tags: numerical-methods

I am doing Bisection method of numerical analysis. The question I encountered is as follows

To determine the interval of unit length which contains the smallest positive root of $x^{3}-5x-1=0$. Hence determine the number of iterations required so that |Error|$\leq 10^{-3}$

I am having problem with first part. Since I have to find an interval of unit length, I computed $f(0) = -1$ and $f(-1)=3$. So by IVT there has to be a root in $(-1,0)$. But similar thing occurs in $(2,3)$. How do I know which interval has the smallest positive root?

Thanks

Comment: The interval $(-1,0)$ consists of negative numbers, so cannot contain a positive root.

Comment: What sign will the root in $(-1,0)$ have?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok i got it now. What about third root?

Comment: Since $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} (x^3 - 5x - 1) = -\infty$, you know the third root is smaller than $-1$ (it lies between $-3$ and $-2$, but we don't need to know that).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks

Comment: Please just draw a careful graph of $y=x^3 - 5x -1,$ http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph  I have a good calculator, I find out the values for small integers, then numbers like 0.2 and so on, before long i have a very good idea what is going on. Graphing, by hand, is a valuable skill.

Comment: There's 1 maximum positive solutions, and 2 maximum negative solutions by Descartes sign change rule.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Descartes sign change? what is it?

Comment: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/drofsign.htm

Comment: A way to determine the maximum negative or real root of a polynomial. Since there con only be 1 maximum positive root, which you have shown the interval for this is the only one. (I made an error in a previous comment, and fixed it)

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Thanks